# YouTubeStandAlonePlayer(Android Player API) lightbox mode doesn't a have fullscreen button?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying out the [Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) and I noticed that while using the YouTubeStandAlonePlayer class, there's no fullscreen button in the player UI when playing the video in lightbox mode.

Is there a way you can customize the player UI to show the fullscreen button?

I look up the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer) but don't see any more info

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playVideoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_video_button);

        playVideoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = null;
        if (v == playVideoButton) {
            intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                    this, DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID, 0, true, true);
        }
}
```